# Laplace Transforms, show the relationship between the 2 expressions

Tags: control-theory

Follow the link

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Z1U.png)

rewrite: 
$(A\sin \omega*t$)u(t) - $(A\sin \omega*t$)u(t-T/2)

u(t) is the unit step function

L(f1(t)) -> $(\frac{A*\omega}{s^2 + \omega^2}$) - $(\frac{A*\omega}{s^2 + \omega^2})(\frac{e^(-s*\tau)}{s}$)

tau = T/2

All I can think to do is take the Laplace transform. What steps would I take to solve the problem? I don't understand what the problem is asking me to do. Where does the + sign come from in the second expression? Thanks

Comment: I assume that u(t) is the unit step function?

Comment: yes it is, sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to make it that complicated.

$$f_1(t)=A \sin(\omega t)[u(t)-u(t-\frac{T}2)]$$

$$f_2(t)=A \sin(\omega t) u(t) + A \sin(\omega (t-\frac{T}2))u(t-\frac{T}2)$$

The problem is to show how $f_1=f_2$.

Just simplify the second part of $f_2$:

$$\sin(\omega (t-\frac{T}2))=\sin(\omega t-\frac{\omega T}2)=\sin(\omega t -\frac{2\pi}2)=\sin(\omega t -\pi)=-\sin(\omega t)$$

$$f_2(t)=A \sin(\omega t) u(t) + A [-\sin(\omega t)]u(t-\frac{T}2)$$
$$=A \sin(\omega t) u(t) - A \sin(\omega t) u(t-\frac{T}2)$$$$=A \sin(\omega t) [u(t) - u(t-\frac{T}2)]=f_1(t)$$

Comment: Thanks, turns out the sin function was supposed to be abs(sin). My instructor forgot to include it.

Comment: @ellsmirip25 no need to have an abs as the sin function is positive in that domain.